# op_ici_install() function call within RTI callback causing OPNET to crash

Tags: opnet

I use `Opnet` in conjunction with other simulators for co-simulation under High Level Architecture.

Upon receiving co-simulation messages from other simulators (interaction-receive / attribute update), the callback routine attempts to schedule remote interrupt with ICI installed.

However, the `op_ici_install()` function call within the callback routine always result in fatal crash, with error `Access Violation Exception`, hence I suspect that `op_ici_install` function
cannot be used from within RTI callback.

Please suggest probable causes and work around solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More experiments confirmed that `op_ici_install()` would not work on an RTI callback. Work around solution is to use another process communication mechanism `op_ev_state_install()`, which can achieve pretty much the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right, Don't use the ICI with an interrupt. Event state will provide what you want to do.

Comment: How does this add information to the accepted answer?